# Weird situation crash on device but work in the simulator IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, simulator

My app works fine previously, but today, I don't know why it's not working in my device but working in my simulator.

The error is so weird:

[image]

It's just not working anymore, I don't know how to debug and see the specific error, it's working all fine in the simulator.

I got more detail error message:

```
[OS_tcp_connection_destination numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized
```

What is that?

Comment: try to reinstall app on the device

Comment: @hal9000 I did so many times, still not working.

Comment: your self.window isn't nil ?

Comment: @hal9000 Yes, it's not nil, and has the frame.

Comment: post all the code where you setup window

Comment: before that you can clean your project and delete derived data

Comment: Clean your build folder.  Hold down option (alt) while clicking Clean in the Product menu.  After the clean, delete the app on the device and build again.

Comment: You set have to implement `UITableViewDataSource`'s `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method you in the class is set to be tableview delegate (seems to be `SideMenuViewController`).

Comment: weird, numberOfSectionsInTableView is not a required datasource method

Comment: Check wether you have `@synthesize window` property in `AppDelegate.m`